# Unable to activate latest Katalon studio Testing tool

Tags: testing, automated-tests, free, katalon-studio

I planned to use Katalon (Free) with Jenkins.

After populating all the headless scripts for several testing over past 3 months I decided to go live on our production servers.

I registered with a new user email id and password and I'm able to login with the credentials here:  https://www.katalon.com/sign-in/

However, after downloading the latest katalon from here:

[image]

Once downloaded and extracted; I'm unable to use the software with the same credentials i used above to login. I get Unautorized message when trying to Activate the tool.

Note: I do not wish to used the licensed (paid) version but the free version that used to work before.

[image]

I was a little concerned reading this thread with the similar issue.

https://forum.katalon.com/t/question-is-katalon-studio-still-free/32780/6

Can you please suggest if I downloaded the incorrect setup, or if, I m missing something activating the tool or if Katalon has actually tricked us into believing this was free which it is no more !! . If so any alternate free solution / tool to katalon ? Please suggest.

Comment: so you did change the pc which you are working?

Comment: The working old Katalon was on a different system using a different login credentials. This new non-working Katalon is on a fresh system with a new set of credentials. Do the new is not affected by the old in any way

Comment: Please, consider providing feedback. JanZ [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691024/2125110) is correct, but not marked as accepted answer. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 7 of Katalon Studio, CI with Jenkins only is working with Katalon Runtime Engine. This tool is not free.

See: https://www.katalon.com/pricing/